# How to apply more than two style to one control in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="Style_1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Style_2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Style_3" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="MultyStyles" Margin="160,136,248,222"/>
```

Now i want to apply Above **Three Style** into one control.I can apply two style to one Controle like below.

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="Style_1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Style_2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style_1}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Style_3" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="MultyStyles" Margin="160,136,248,222" Style="{StaticResource Style_2}"/>
</Grid>
```

But i don't know to apply more than two style to one control. what should i do for that ?

Comment: What stops you from basing 3 on 2 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this using the BasedOn logic you've already used.  As an option, you can use Triggers to change the style if it makes sense in your project.